# Access GitVersion variable in azure pipeline for javascript build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've got the following pipeline:

```
steps:

- task: GitVersion@4

- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]$(GitVersion.FullSemVer")'

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  displayName: "NPM Install"

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    customCommand: 'run-script build'
  displayName: "NPM Build"

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    customCommand: 'npm version $(buildVersion)'
  displayName: "Add version"
```

But I can't get access to the GitVersion output. I've tried with simply referencing $(GitVersion.FullSemVer) as well, but it gives the same result. The output from npm version is:

```
[command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\10.16.0\x64\npm.cmd npm version "$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)'""
Usage: npm <command>
```

If I write out the actual variables it looks fine.

**Edit:** It seems the problem at hand is that the version number is quoted, which *npm* doesn't like. So the question is more how to make that *not* happen.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `"` in `$(GitVersion.FullSemVer")`, just remove it and it will be fine:

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)'
```

For example:

```
- task: GitVersion@4

- script: 'echo ##vso[setvariable variable=buildVersion]$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)'

- script: 'echo $(buildVersion)'
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Good catch with the extra quote, but it wasn't unfortunately it. I've realized what it is though. When I inject the variable it gets qouted; `\npm.cmd version "0.1.0+54'""` which is the problem.

Comment: Great catch too :)